# What's wrong with my proof of the proposition about this continuous curve?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here's an example from my analysis book.

"*Let $B\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be the image of a continuous segment of parametric curves with at least one component having continuous derivatives, then B is a zero area set.*"

I tried to prove the example problem myself, but the proof I gave did not use such a condition as the existence of a derivative. Obviously if this condition is removed there is a counterexample, such as the *Peano curve*, then there must be something wrong with my proof, but I haven't found anything wrong with it after half a day's looking at it, so can anyone help me out? Thank you very much!

Here's my proof:

**Proof.** Let the parametric equations of the curve be $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ for $\alpha\le t \le \beta$, where $x,y$ are continuous functions on interval $[\alpha,\beta]\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Split the interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ by

$$\pi:\alpha=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_{n-1}<t_n=\beta.$$

This defines $n$ small rectangles, denote

$$I_i:=x\left([t_{i-1},t_{i}]\right)\times y\left([t_{i-1},t_{i}]\right) \text{ for }i=1,2,\dots,n.$$

Apparently there is $B\subset \bigcup_{1\le i\le n}I_i$. By Most Value Theorem, there exists points $\xi_{i},\Xi_{i},\lambda_{i},\Lambda_{i} \in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]$ such that

$$I_i=[x(\xi_i),x(\Xi_i)]\times[y(\lambda_i),y(\Lambda_i)]\text{ for }i=1,2,\dots,n,$$

since continuous functions preserving connectivity, and any connected subset in $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval.

By Uniform Continuity Theorem, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_i>0$ such that if
$t_{i}-t_{i-1}<\delta_i$, then

$$x(\Xi_i)-x(\xi_i)<\sqrt{\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2^i}},~y(\Lambda_i)-y(\lambda_i)<\sqrt{\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2^i}}\text{ for }i=1,2,\dots,n.$$

Then the area of $I_i$ there is $\sigma(I_i)<\varepsilon/2^{i}$. Consequently, as long as $||\pi||<\delta(:=\min_{1\le i\le n}\delta_i)$, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma(I_i)<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2^{i}}<\varepsilon\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^i}=\varepsilon.$$

Hence, $B$ is a zero area set.$~\blacksquare$

---

The problem has already been solved.

If I choose $\delta_i$ for each interval, then I cannot change $\pi$ such that $||\pi||<\delta$, because $\delta$ changes with it.

If I generally choose $\delta$ for the largest interval $[\alpha,\beta]$, then the inquality depend on the index $i$, that's not consistent continuity. If the right side of the inquality changes to $\sqrt{\varepsilon/2^n}$, then $n$ also changes as $||\pi||$ becomes smaller than $\delta$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose $\delta_i$ to depend on $\epsilon$ and $i$, and you choose $t_i$ so that $t_i-t_{i-1}<\delta_i$, then you no longer have the freedom to demand that $t_0,\dots,t_n$ partitions your interval for some $n$.  You may have $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\delta_i< b-a,$$ for example, in which case there is no partition of $[a,b]$, for any $n$, satisfying the inequality $t_i-t_{i-1}<\delta_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: what if I choose $\delta>0$ such that any two points $\tau,\lambda\in[\alpha,\beta]$ (instead of $[t_{i-1},t_{i}]$), if $|\tau-\lambda|<\delta$ then $x(\tau)-x(\lambda),y(\tau)-y(\lambda)<\sqrt{\varepsilon/2^i}$, as long as $||\pi||<\delta$, did it still has the same result?

Comment: @PauseAndPonder Now you have chosen a single  $\delta$, so you cannot have it depend on $i$.

Comment: What exactly does "depend on $i$" mean? If I have $||\pi||<\delta$, then the distance between the max-min points on each interval should be less than or equal to the length of the corresponding interval, thus less than or equal to $||\pi||$, less than $\delta$. So the distance between the max-min values on each interval satisfies that inequality, is there any problem? (っ °Д °;)っ

Comment: @PauseAndPonder You originally chose $\delta_i$ to be small enough so that $$x(\Xi_i)-x(\xi_i)<\sqrt{\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2^i}},$$ provided that $t_i-t_{i-1}<\delta_i$.  If you instead choose a single $\delta$ independently of $i$, you no longer have that inequality for all $i$.  Nor do you have your new inequality $$x(\tau)-x(\lambda),y(\tau)-y(\lambda)<\sqrt{\varepsilon/2^i},$$ since that also includes $i$.

Comment: For any given $\varepsilon>0$, doesn't $\delta$ depend only on the functions $x,y$ and on the whole large interval $[\alpha,\beta]$? Then I just have to let each small interval have a maximum length $||\pi||<\delta$. Then for $\Xi_i,\xi_i\in[t_{i-1},t_{i}]$ of all $i$, it have a distance $||\Xi_i-\xi_i||\le t_i-t_{i-1}\le||\pi||<\delta$. Wouldn't that give an inequality 

$$x(\Xi_i)-x(\xi_i)<\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^i}}\text{?}$$

Comment: If, as you say, $\delta$ depends only on $\varepsilon$ and the functions $x$ and $y$ and the whole large interval, and does not depend on $i$, then you cannot guarantee $$x(\tau)-x(\lambda),y(\tau)-y(\lambda)<\sqrt{\varepsilon/2^i},$$ since the right hand side of the inequality has an $i$ in it.  The right hand side of the preceding inequality has to be independent of $i$ if you are picking $\delta$ independently of $i$.

Comment: Oh, I got it! My inequality becomes dependent on $i$. Thanks mate!